# RavenDB Spatial Queries Not Returning Results

Tags: ravendb

I'm getting 0 results with the following, which I don't think should be the case.

Query code:

```
 var sourceResults = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Route>("Routes/BySource")
            .WithinRadiusOf(5, toMatch.Source.Location.Latitude, toMatch.Source.Location.Longitude)
            .WhereBetween(r => r.DateTime, minDateTime, maxDateTime).ToArray();
```

Index Code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Index for spatial search by route source.
    /// </summary>
    public class Routes_BySource : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Route>
    {
        public Routes_BySource()
        {
            Map = routes => from r in routes
                            select new { _ = SpatialIndex.Generate(r.Source.Location.Latitude, r.Source.Location.Longitude) };
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
public class Route
{       
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the id.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The id.
    /// </value>        
    public string Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the source.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// From.
    /// </value>
    public Address Source { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets destination.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// To.
    /// </value>
    public Address Destination { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the id of the user who requested the route.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The user id.
    /// </value>
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the date time that the request is for.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The date time.
    /// </value>
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name. This is the formatted full name of the address.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The name.
    /// </value>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the location.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The location.
    /// </value>
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Unit test (calls the query code)

```
        using (var session = Common.DocumentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            var routeService = new RouteService(session);
            var newRoute = new Route
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                DateTime = DateTime.Now,
                UserId = "user",
                Source = new Address { Name = "101 W. 79th St. NY, NY", Location = new Location { Latitude = 32, Longitude = 72 } },
                Destination = new Address { Name = "101 W. 79th St. NY, NY", Location = new Location { Latitude = 32, Longitude = 72 } }
            };
            routeService.Save(newRoute);
            var routes = routeService.Search(newRoute);
            Assert.IsTrue(routes.Any());
        }
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Seems like it should be pretty straightforward...

Thanks

Comment: What are the values that you are passing to the WithinRadiusOf ?

Comment: The ones mentioned in the lat/long of the unit test

Comment: For the purposes of the test, I'm searching on the same value I just saved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you have routeService.Save(newRoute);, I'm used to seeing session.Store(newRoute); then session.SaveChanges();

Things don't get written to the database until you call session.SaveChanges();

But you need to give ravenDB time to index the changes.  I suggest to use the "wait for non stale results", I don't remember the code for that right now but if you google ravendb non-stale results.

Comment: You win!! Thank you! Added  session.Query<Route>().Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults()).ToArray();